# Git: automatically add all files under a dir

Tags: git

Within my working dir, I have a lot of files:

```
file1.html
file2.html
file3.html
sub_dir1/
sub_dir2/
data/
output_result/
```

In this repo, not all files are under git, some are just supplementary files and I want to keep them aside. For example, `file3.html` is not under git, and some dataset within `data` are not under git.

When I working on it, I use `git add -u`, for updating changes on files already tracked by git. This is fine.

But now, I regularly output results into `output_result/`. So there are always new files in this dir. I want to update those files.

How can I add this file with ease?

---

`git add -u` is not sufficient anymore. I need to run `git add output_result` as well, and that feels repetitive.

I can add all untracked files into `.gitignore`, and then do it with `git add .`. But the problem is I have too many files that are not under git. (`data/` folder has a lot of sub-folders.) Adding them manually is simply impossible.

Is there a `.git-must-add-dir` file that can help to autotrack the `output_result/`? So I don't have to add them by hand?

Comment: You can use wild cards in an ignore file

Comment: @MichaelBurr, as I said above. Too many files and dir need to put into `.gitignore`, doing it by hand is very hard. Or, can I add `data/sub_dir` first, and then ignore the whole `data/`?

Comment: Automating the action of adding files to git would mean you dont review your change on commit. I dont think its a good habbit. You should review each file you changed or added upon commit. Why would you add them automatically without reviewing them?

Comment: @Lynch, not necessarily, I use `git status` to view the file before commit them. So there is a review process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust your .gitignore file like:

```
data/*
```

or if you want to ignore whole data directory, then just write as:

```
data
```

Comment: So you suggest add file into `.gitignore`, and then do `git add .` for tracking files?

Comment: @cqcn1991 Yes, .gitignore could use wildchar, so you don't have every file you want to ignore write in it, just write ignore rules.

Comment: That's ok. But I also have some other files in the root dir. I can add them into `.gitignore` by hand. But They are necessary files, I just don't want to publish them in my repo. I feel `.gitignore` is for `uncessary files`, like `.pyc` etc.

Comment: No, `.gitignore` is for files you don't want to put under version control not for unnecessary files.